# Displaying and review pdf files in Adobe reader tool

Tags: vb.net

I use code to view pdf files in adobe reader tool then store them in sql server database,
What I want is a way to display these stored files when I double click on the file name in datagridview
I use this code to display pdf files:

```
Private Sub btnNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewItem.Click

        txtItemNO.Text = GetmaxID()

        btnSaveItem.Enabled = True

        ofd.Filter = "pdf Files|*.pdf"
        If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            txtpdfPath.Text = ofd.FileName
            AxAcroPDF1.src = txtpdfPath.Text
        End If

    End Sub
```

and this code to save them in database:

```
 Private Sub btnSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveItem.Click

        Try
            cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into TBL_Attaches (AttachID, AttachName, AttachDate, Picture, CatID) values (@AttachID, @AttachName, @AttachDate, @Picture, @CatID)", con)

            con.Open()
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@AttachID", txtItemNO.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@AttachName", txtItemName.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@AttachDate", dtDateSave.Value)

                Dim fs As New FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
                Dim Filepdf() As Byte = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)
                .AddWithValue("@Picture", Filepdf)

                .AddWithValue("@CatID", cmbItemCat.SelectedValue)
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Save")

            dgsittings()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and this is the code I used to show files name in datagridview:

```
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select TBL_Attaches.AttachID, TBL_Attaches.AttachName, TBL_Attaches.AttachDate, TBL_CatFailes.CatName from TBL_Attaches inner join TBL_CatFailes on TBL_Attaches.CatID = TBL_CatFailes.CatID", con)
        Dim dtG As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(dtG)
        dgAttached.DataSource = dtG
```

I just want to display pdf file when I double click on it's name in the datagridview

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?  Retrieving the binary value from the db or displaying the pdf?  How about showing us what you've attempted in that space?

Comment: I just want to display the pdf file

Comment: Is it any more difficult than saving the stream to a temporary file, then using a process.start() to open the file with the default viewer?

Comment: would you please tell me how to do so? I just want a code to display pdf file in adobe reader tool when I double click on it's name in datagridview

Comment: Which part?  Retrieving the image from the db, saving the stream to a temporary file, or opening the temporary file using the default viewer?  Three very distinct operations.

Comment: Retrieving the pdf files from the database

Comment: Now I'm confused as to your problem, you're already doing a query on TBL_Attaches, all you need to do is add the Picture column to the New SqlDataAdapter query and it's retrieved from the DB.  Then like mentioned above, save that byte array as a temporary file, then just use a process.Start() to open it

Comment: would you please write me the code because I find it's hard to do so